React-native positional binaural audio
I'm thinking about creating an app that simply play a sonar like audio coming from a given coordinate. It must read my current location and orientation and change the sound source accordingly. So I need a way of playing a "moving" sound as I move the phone. I've mentioned binaural as it will give better experience. Any library that you know will work?
I've searched libraries but could not find any specific for text native that can generate binaural positional sounds from a moving target
